# How to prevent brute forcing registration on mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, ddos

In my mvc wen app I have a registration form page. the fields to be filled by user are :
UserName , Password , ConfirmPassword , EMail . I want to disable the possibility of brute forcing and automating the registration. I don't want to use captcha as with all respect it makes a lot of users abandon the registration .
Is there a different solution in MVC to do that ?
I've used [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute but noticed that I can catch the "__RequestVerificationToken" param in request and automate more request with the same one just changing email and username .

Comment: You could do CSRF but this doesn't stop browser bots from registering. You don't have any other choice than checking if the user is human which captcha is for. Even easy captcha's is easily defeated by browser bots. But maybe have a random question asked as the last input box on your registration form.

Comment: @ooo He is talking about registration not signing in.